# nVidia Device missing in my Vaio

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sony-vaio

I own a Vaio VGN-SZ38GP which came with two graphics cards, nVidia and Intel. Display is  regulated through the stamina-speed switch present on the laptop. Stamina switch is for Intel graphics and speed switch is for nVidia graphics.

The switch started malfunctioning some time back and now the system is stuck with intel graphics. I did a lot of research, Q&A over the internet but couldn't find any solution. Some guy also refereed that the GPU is dead!

The device doesn't show-up on the device manager. Installing of nVidia drivers shows an error "Failed to update driver". Is the GPU really dead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems reasonable that windows can't see the card since it is turned off. Installing the drivers won't make any difference since it is the actual hardware that is disabled.

You should be able to fix this by activating the card in your BIOS. Look for a "graphics device" or "GPU" or "OPTIMUS" menu in your BIOS. In there, you should be given an option to use Nvidia, Intel or "OS Select" which is what you have activated at the moment. Choosing Nvidia, should let you use your card but you will loose the ability to dynamically switch from one to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I looked into my BIOS but couldn't find any graphics device, GPU, Optimus, or any menu that links to the gfx cards. There are only four tabs: basic, advanced, boot, exit.

Comment: none of the tabs contained any option for video.

Comment: @RickeshJohn, it should be in there somewhere...

Comment: I doubled checked it, even entered every editable BIOS option. There is no provision of altering the status of my gfx cards. The only editable option related to gfx is that of "wide LCD display". I changed it but it didn't solve my case. :(

Comment: What BIOS do you have?

Comment: Its of Phoenix Technologies. The header on BIOS read `Phoenix Trusted Core Setup Utility`.

Comment: @RickeshJohn, you could try opening the case as described [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/sony/427240-sony-vgn-sz450n-stamina-speed.html)

Comment: I don't have the tools to open my laptop. Guess that not an option I can follow. :(

Comment: All it takes is a screwdriver...

Comment: :D :D :D 
I would definitely try it, when I get one.